# Converting IPublishedContent to Dtos and performance

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this before?

I should start by saying I'm not using ModelsBuilder for this project. I was having too many problems with it so abandoned that route.

I am however converting IPublishedContent items into Dtos within my app, using a converter class that basically maps the values. The problem I'm finding is that it's causing a massive slowdown in my code execution, especially in comparision to just getting the raw IPublishedContent collection.

To give you an example, I have a 'Job' document type. Jobs can be assigned to workers. In one of my services I need to get a collection of all jobs assigned to a worker:

```
public IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> GetJobsForWorker(int workerId)
{
    var jobs = Umbraco.TypedContent(1234);

    return jobs.Descendants("job").Where(j => j.GetPropertyValue<int>("assignedWorker") == workerId).ToList();
}
```

This function returns a collection of IPublishContent, which returns lightning fast, as I'd expect.

However if I try and convert the results to my job Dto class, it goes from taking 0 seconds, to around 7.. and that's just returning a collection of ~7 from ~20 or so records:

```
public IEnumerable<Job> GetJobsCompletedByWorker(int workerId)
{
    var jobs = Umbraco.TypedContent(1234);

    return jobs.Descendants("job").Where(j => j.GetPropertyValue<int>("assignedWorker") == workerId).Select(node => _jobConverter.ConvertToModel(_umbracoHelper, node)).ToList();
}
```

Now I'm not doing any complex processing in this converter, it's just mapping the values as such:

```
public class JobConverter
{
    public Job ConvertToModel(UmbracoHelper umbracoHelper, IPublishedContent node)
    {
        if (node != null)
        {
            var job = new Job
            {
                Id = node.Id,
                Property1 = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("property1"),
                Property2 = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("property2")
                ... more properties
            };

            return job;
       }

       return null;
   }
}
```

I'm not really sure what best practice is here? Is there something I'm missing that's causing this slowdown? I only ask because I've used ModelsBuilder before which essentially does the same thing ie. map umbraco fields to properties, and yet there's nowhere near the same delay.

Ultimately I could just use IPublishedContent, but it makes for messy code and it's far more difficult to understand.

I just wonder if anyone's been in this situation before and how they handled it?

Thanks

Comment: What will happen if you put ToList before your Select? So that you will have Where().ToList().Select(...).ToList().

Comment: Made no difference.. in fact if anything it seemed to take a tiny bit longer, plus I'm not sure what difference it would be expected to make?

Comment: if you don't want to use ModelsBuilder, take a look at Ditto instead:  https://github.com/leekelleher/umbraco-ditto

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I actually had a helper method running on one of my properties that was querying member data, which made a database call.. hence the slowdown!